# Any pattern for delaying processing of a (JMS) message until another task completes

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, message-queue

Is there a good pattern in microservices systems for delaying the processing of a JMS message until some other task has been completed. Let's say, for example, a message is sent to a topic when a customer makes a transaction. Two microservices receive the event, one of which updates details of how much a customer has spent on different types of product. The second decides on a marketing message to send based on the customer's most commonly purchased product. Now, the second service needs the results of the first, but both get the event at the same time so if the second service carries out its task immediately it may make the wrong decision.

Obviously the second service could poll the first until it gets the answer, but this seems bad practice as the message processing would be slow and messages should ideally be dealt with quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You described two things that need to run, `update()` and `send_ad()`.
There is an edge in the dependency graph between them,
so update must precede ad.

That's pretty straightforward.
Do we have scenario 1 in the accompanying dep graph?
No, we have scenario 2.
[image: pair of dependency graphs]

We want the "buy" transaction message to be sent
to a single subscriber, update().
It will manipulate relevant databases, commit,
and at the end will send a message to another subscriber, send_ad().
At that point we can do DB queries to our heart's content,
confident that there are no races.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the answer but was hoping there might be a nice way to do it without introducing a new event.